# How can I get information about TLB memory on macOS

Tags: osx, memory, cache

How can I get information about TLB cache memory on macOS? Things like number of entries, associativity, covered page sizes. I have tried to using tools like cpuinfo_x86 but it doesn't prompt much information about TLB